# insert new field in mongodb database

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm a beginner in mongodb and pymongo and I'm working on a project where I have a students mongodb collection . What I want is to add a new field and specifically an adrress of a student to each element in my collection (the field is obviously added everywhere as null and will be filled by me later).

However when I try using this specific example to add a new field I get a the following syntax error:

```
 client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/') #connect to local mongodb

 db = client['InfoSys']   #choose infosys database
 students = db['Students']

 students.update(  {  $set : {"address":1} }  ) #set address field to every column (error happens here)
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer here is spot on, but it looks like your question may relate more to PyMongo and how it manages updates to collections. https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html

According to the docs, it looks like you may want to use the 'update_many()' function. You will still need to make your query (all documents, in this case) as the first argument, and the second argument is the operation to perform on all records.

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/') #connect to local mongodb

db = client['InfoSys']   #choose infosys database
students = db['Students']

sudents.update_many({}, {$set : {"address":1}})
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the update operation in wrong manner. Update operation is having the following syntax:

```js
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   <options>
)
```

The main parameter `<query>` is not at all mentioned. It has to be at least empty like `{}`, In your case the following query will work:

```js
db.students.update(
  {}, // To update the all the documents.
  {$set : {"address": 1}}, // Update the address field.
  {multi: true} // To do multiple updates, otherwise Mongo will just update the first matching document.
)
```

So, in python, you can use `update_many` to achieve this. So, it will be like:

```py
students.update_many(
  {},
  {"$set" : {"address": 1}}
)
```

You can read more about this operation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/).

Comment: so the empty {} targets my whole collection ? Instead of saying {"id " : "1234"} for example

Comment: Yes, `{}` will target all the documents in the collection. If you want to specifically modify the document with `id` as `1234`, then you should specify `{"id " : "1234"}` instead of `{}`.

Comment: I now get the following error 
    students.update( {},{'$set':{"address:1"}}  , {multi:true} )
NameError: name 'multi' is not defined

Comment: I just now saw that you are using PyMongo driver, you can use `update_many` instead of  `update` and ignore `multi` option.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by iterating through every element in my collection and inserting the address field to each one.

```
 cursor = students.find({})
 for student in cursor :
      students.update_one(student, {'$set': {'address': '1'}})
```